# getting the value from an arraylist of objects that has an attribute of another object arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

for my college project, I am trying to implement a sectioned recyclerview with the section title as date, and a list of appointments as the contents, in each row of appointments I want to display some fields, in which I have created the apnmntDetails class as below:

```
public class apnmtDetails {
private String BarberName;
private String Barbershop;
private String ServiceName;
private String ServiceType;
private String Servicestatus;
private String ServicePrice;
private String ServiceTime;

public apnmtDetails(String barberName, String barbershop,
                    String serviceName, String serviceType,
                    String servicestatus, String servicePrice,
                    String serviceTime) {
    BarberName = barberName;
    Barbershop = barbershop;
    ServiceName = serviceName;
    ServiceType = serviceType;
    Servicestatus = servicestatus;
    ServicePrice = servicePrice;
    ServiceTime = serviceTime;
}

public String getBarberName() {
    return BarberName;
}

public void setBarberName(String barberName) {
    BarberName = barberName;
}

public String getBarbershop() {
    return Barbershop;
}

public void setBarbershop(String barbershop) {
    Barbershop = barbershop;
}

public String getServiceName() {
    return ServiceName;
}

public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
    ServiceName = serviceName;
}

public String getServiceType() {
    return ServiceType;
}

public void setServiceType(String serviceType) {
    ServiceType = serviceType;
}

public String getServicestatus() {
    return Servicestatus;
}

public void setServicestatus(String servicestatus) {
    Servicestatus = servicestatus;
}

public String getServicePrice() {
    return ServicePrice;
}

public void setServicePrice(String servicePrice) {
    ServicePrice = servicePrice;
}

public String getServiceTime() {
    return ServiceTime;
}

public void setServiceTime(String serviceTime) {
    ServiceTime = serviceTime;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "apnmtDetails{" +
            "BarberName='" + BarberName + '\'' +
            ", Barbershop='" + Barbershop + '\'' +
            ", ServiceName='" + ServiceName + '\'' +
            ", ServiceType='" + ServiceType + '\'' +
            ", Servicestatus='" + Servicestatus + '\'' +
            ", ServicePrice='" + ServicePrice + '\'' +
            ", ServiceTime='" + ServiceTime + '\'' +
            '}';
}}
```

after that, I created a section class that holds the field of the sectionName and sectionItem, where sectionitem is an arraylist of the apnmntDetails class, the code is below:

```
public class Section {

private String SectionName;
private ArrayList<apnmtDetails> SectionItem;

public Section(String sectionName, ArrayList<apnmtDetails> sectionItem) {
    SectionName = sectionName;
    SectionItem = sectionItem;
}

public String getSectionName() {
    return SectionName;
}

public void setSectionName(String sectionName) {
    SectionName = sectionName;
}

public ArrayList<apnmtDetails> getSectionItem() {
    return SectionItem;
}

public void setSectionItem(ArrayList<apnmtDetails> sectionItem) {

    this.SectionItem.addAll(sectionItem);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Section{" +
            "SectionName='" + SectionName + '\'' +
            ", SectionItem=" + SectionItem +
            '}';
}}
```

Right now, in the activity, I initialize all the value by querying from firebase firestore:

```
 private void initData(){

    db.collection("appointmentsColl").document(UserId)
            .collection("Date")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                            db.collection("appointmentsColl").document(UserId)
                                    .collection("Date").document(document.getId())
                                    .collection("appointmentsID")
                                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                    for (DocumentSnapshot querysnapshot: task.getResult()){
                                        apnmtDetails details = new apnmtDetails(querysnapshot.getString("barber"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("barber"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("name"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("type"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("status"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("price"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("time slot"));

                                        apnmntList.add(details);
                                        Log.i("apnmntList", apnmntList.toString());

                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            sectionList.add(new Section(document.getString("date"),apnmntList));

                        }

                        for(int i = 0; i<sectionList.size(); i++)
                        Log.i("sectionList", sectionList.get(i).toString());

                    }else{

                        Toast.makeText(HomePage.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.i("Check", e.toString() );
        }
    });
}
```

the problem is that when i try to print the value of the sectionlist, only the sectionName comes out correctly, whereas the appntmntDetails class's object did not appear as i want it to,
this is the logcat:

```
2021-03-04 14:57:06.748 4678-4678/com.example.homebarberv1 I/sectionList: Section{SectionName='4/AUG/2021', SectionItem=[]}
2021-03-04 14:57:07.029 4678-4678/com.example.homebarberv1 I/apnmntList: [apnmtDetails{BarberName='vAN7LYKoddRX2cQlogQtStOueKt2', Barbershop='vAN7LYKoddRX2cQlogQtStOueKt2', ServiceName='normal cut', ServiceType='Normal', Servicestatus='On hold', ServicePrice='4', ServiceTime='07:00 to 07:30'}]
```

firebase is not the problem as the value is retrieved correctly as shown in the logcat with the tag of apnmntList, but when printing the value using the servicelist arraylist, the value did not appear.

im still a bit unfamiliar and new with Java so, i will greatly appreciate if anyone can help in pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `sectionList.add(new Section(document.getString("date"),apnmntList));` inside onComplete() call back method. Because this is a call back method is suspended and control jumps to execute code after call back code block. One more thing you should initialize apnmntList before for loop, because new list has to be saved for each Section.
I have made changes to onComplete() method, just have a look :

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    apnmntList = new ArrayList();
    for (DocumentSnapshot querysnapshot: task.getResult()){
        apnmtDetails details = new apnmtDetails(querysnapshot.getString("barber"),
                querysnapshot.getString("barber"),
                querysnapshot.getString("name"),
                querysnapshot.getString("type"),
                querysnapshot.getString("status"),
                querysnapshot.getString("price"),
                querysnapshot.getString("time slot"));

        apnmntList.add(details);
        Log.i("apnmntList", apnmntList.toString());

    }
    sectionList.add(new Section(document.getString("date"),apnmntList));
}
```

Comment: hello sir, ive tried to implement the fix that you recommended, I am able to print the serviceList when I put the logcat inside of the for loop, but when I tried to print it outside of the onComplete, it came out empty, how can I work around this?

Comment: Is it printing correctly inside onComplete() ? See, call back methods are like Asynchronous process, so you should not prepare sectionList outside onComplete.

Comment: Alright sir, thank you very much for your help